# converting javascript function to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I've been struggling to convert a JavaScript function...

Original code:

```
function calcTotal(){

//get value of select(tickets)
var ticketCost = 0;
if(document.moaflevent.moaflmember.value=="Yes") {
    var ticketPrice = 35;

}else {
    var ticketPrice = 40;

}
ticketCost = (document.moaflevent.tickets.options[document.moaflevent.tickets.selectedIndex].value)*ticketPrice;

document.moaflevent.displaytotal.value= formatCurrency(ticketCost);
document.moaflevent.total.value=ticketCost;
}
```

my jquery syntax:

```
function calcTotal() {

    //get value of select(tickets)
    //var ticketCost = 0;

    var ticketCost = 0;

    if ($('#moaflmember').val() == "Yes") {
        var ticketPrice = 10;
    } else {
        $ticketPrice = 10;
    }

    $('#eachTicket').text($ticketPrice);
    $ticketCost = $('#tickets').val() * $ticketPrice;

    $('#displaytotal').val().toUSD($ticketCost);    
    $('#total').val().toUSD($ticketCost);   
}
```

it's not working, the total is not updating when selecting membership or number of tickets...

jsfiddle says my js is good but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here...

http://jsfiddle.net/kv7L0c5d/5/

Comment: There are a couple of differences. For one, you don't use `var` in the `else` branch, and both branches return `10`. But first I'd check if expressions like `$('#moaflmember')` does indeed find an element.

Comment: I tried your fiddle. It *does* show errors if you check the console tab. The first error you get (when you select 'Yes') can be solved by selecting `no wrap` in the Javascript options of the fiddle ([update](http://jsfiddle.net/kv7L0c5d/9/)). After that, you will see the *actual* errors, which are mostly related to the fact that `ticketPrice` is not the same as `$ticketPrice`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/q2gqc1yo/

Comment: Another addition. Use `onclick` instead of `onchange` for selects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You are using an inconsistent mixture of `$ticketPrice` and `ticketPrice`. These are not the same thing.
- You have not declared the `$ticketCost` variable.
- `toUSD` is not a method on the string datatype, so you cannot call `$('#displaytotal').val().toUSD($ticketCost);`

The following works:

```
function calcTotal() {
    var ticketPrice = 0,
        ticketCost;

    if ($('#moaflmember').val() == "Yes") {
        ticketPrice = 10;
    } else {
        ticketPrice = 10;
    }

    $('#eachTicket').text(ticketPrice);
    ticketCost = $('#tickets').val() * ticketPrice;

    $('#displaytotal').val(toUSD(ticketCost));
    $('#total').val(toUSD(ticketCost));
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kv7L0c5d/10/

Comment: don't forget to catch errors that'll happen if the input can't be converted to a number...

Comment: Just in case this helps, if you are reading input as a number use `parseInt($('#tickets').val(), 10)` this treats the input as a base-10 number

Comment: @Alnitak Valid point, but in this case `#tickets` is a dropdown box, so there shouldn't be any concern of non-numeric inputs there.